# Remove table name from select queries

Tags: postgresql, clojure

I am using `next.jdbc` with `postgres`.

When I query a table the response data has table name prepended to the keys.

```
accounts/email: "email",
accounts/created_on: "2020-09-20T09:33:23Z",
accounts/last_login: "2020-09-20T09:33:23Z"
```

How do we get

```
email: "email",
created_on: "2020-09-20T09:33:23Z",
last_login: "2020-09-20T09:33:23Z"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is explained in the documentation for `next.jdbc`. The **Getting Started** guide shows how to do this, using the `as-unqualified-maps` builder function. See https://cljdoc.org/d/seancorfield/next.jdbc/CURRENT/doc/getting-started#options--result-set-builders

But I would strongly recommend you get used to working with qualified keywords in hash maps: they are idiomatic in Clojure and that's why they are the default in `next.jdbc`.